# Swift 3 compiler in terminal

Tags: swift, terminal, swift3

I've downloaded the Xcode 8.0 beta, which includes the updated Swift 3 compiler. **Is it possible to use the Swift 3 compiler on the terminal?**

For example, I can use the "Swift (filename)" command to compile and run Swift 2.2 code in the terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## TL;DR

Since you've already got Xcode 8 beta installed, this should work:

`/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift`

### Smoke Test

```bash
$ /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift -v
Apple Swift version 3.0 (swiftlang-800.0.30 clang-800.0.24)
...
```

### Detailed Example

Here's a complete example using the example code for the [Swift Package Manager](https://swift.org/package-manager/#example-usage).

```bash
$ git clone https://github.com/apple/example-package-dealer
Cloning into 'example-package-dealer'...
remote: Counting objects: 21, done.
remote: Total 21 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 21
Unpacking objects: 100% (21/21), done.
Checking connectivity... done.

$ cd example-package-dealer/

$ /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift build
Cloning https://github.com/apple/example-package-deckofplayingcards.git
HEAD is now at 0879cff Merge pull request #1 from kostiakoval/master
...
Compile Swift Module 'Dealer' (1 sources)
Linking .build/debug/Dealer

$ .build/debug/Dealer
♣︎7
♠︎7
♠︎Q
♢3
♡6
♡7
♣︎K
♡K
♢2
♢8
```

Answer (score 7):

The command line compiler for Swift is called `swiftc`. The `-h` option will show you the command line options.

The command line tool `swift` is the interactive version of the language.

To pick the version to use, use `xcode-select`. e.g.

```
sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/
```

Comment: Not so simple, you also have "swift build" for compiling swift.org's apps, for example.

Comment: "swift build" is specifically for building SwiftPM packages. "swiftc" will compile a swift file as asked in the question.